# Top down car game (game-maker)

Tags: game-maker

I'm new to programming on game-maker and programming in general. This is probably very easy but i'm unsure of how to go about things.

I am programming a simple top-down car game in which the car drives (forward) by it's self and is steered with the left and right mouse buttons. I attempted to get the car to drive on it's own with:

> speed = 3

This, although making the car go forward, stopped the steering from working somehow and now the car rotates instead of actually turning around the corner.

How can i get the car to drive on it's own and still be able to turn the car?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Here is the code for the truck http://prntscr.com/bynxu3 http://prntscr.com/byny68

Comment: Ik this is a terrible post but i'm honestly clueless right now. Instead of disliking my post please just help me. I've looked all over game maker tutorials and nothing is helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not change `image_angle`, but `direction` instead. Image_angle is juste what you see, direction is the real physics direction.

Replace the code in your link by :

```
direction = direction + 2;
image_angle = direction;
```

Like this, you turn the car, and then align the image on the car orientation.

Comment: Thankyou so much bro ik it's so simple but i would have never known. Maybe one day i wont be such a noob :)

Comment: If my answer was correct, don't forget to accept it :) It was a pleasure.